# Is DataGridDragDropTarget gone from the latest version of Silverlight toolkit?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm using Silverlight 4 and Silverlight Toolkit April 10 release (dll is referenced from this folder: %Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Bin). However, after registering the namespaces, adding `toolkit:DataGridDragDropTarget` to XAML results in this error:

```
`The tag 'DataGridDragDropTarget' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit'.`
```

Though, other DragDropTargets are available: ListBoxDragDropTarget, PanelDragDropTarget, TreeViewDragDropTarget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it was some kind of omission mistake by the toolkit team when preparing the distribution package: if you download the toolkit source code (from here: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/43528) and check the archive's Bin folder, **System.Windows.Controls.Data.Toolkit.dll** dll is there - that's the one that now contains the DataGridDragAndDrop itself. Just copy it to the rest of your tollkit distribution dlls and reference from your project:

```
    <dataToolkit:DataGridDragDropTarget
                x:Name="DragAndDrop"
                xmlns:dataToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Toolkit"
                AllowDrop="True" >
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it is gone from the toolkit, since there are lots of online samples that still use `DataGridDragDropTarget`. I got around this problem by wrapping the grid inside `PanelDragDropTarget` from the toolkit. Works like a charm.

```
<toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget x:Name="DragAndDrop" AllowDrop="True" AllowedSourceEffects="Move" >
   <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="400" Height="400" />
</toolkit:PanelDragDropTarget>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually still in the binaries of the toolkit (at least those distributed via nuget), however it is in a different assembly to the other dragdrop helpers.

You will just need to add the following namespace definition:

```
xmlns:dragdrop="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data.Toolkit"
```